# Why React renders all list items every time new item is added?

Tags: reactjs

There are `List` and `Item` components, to display list of numbers, and the `ListContainer` that adds one number every second.

`Item` prints to console every time its rendered.

It seems like the expected behaviour would be to see just 3 lines in console, one `render` for every `Item`. But what actually happens - every time a new item added all the components get re-rendered and the output is

```
rendering item 1
rendering item 1
rendering item 2
rendering item 1
rendering item 2
rendering item 3
```

Why that happening? Isn't React supposed to check for every components `current_props === new_props`? In our case the props for `Item value=1` hasn't been changed. Why it has been rendered 3 times?

The code:

```
class ListContainer extends React.Component {
  state = { values: [1] }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Adding new item every seconds
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ values: [...this.state.values, 2] }), 1000)
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ values: [...this.state.values, 3] }), 2000)
  }

  render() { return <List values={this.state.values}/> }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.values.map((value) => <Item key={value} value={value}/>)}
    </div>
  }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props
    console.log(`rendering item ${value}`)
    return <div>{value}</div>
  }
}

React.render(<ListContainer />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Just use `React.PureComponent` in `Item` class instead of `React.Component`

Comment: "Isn't React supposed to check for every components current_props === new_props?" No. As suggested, see [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcomponent). Also, rendering is not expensive most of the time, DOM change is.

Comment: props are checked only when you are using PureComponent. If not used then where parent is rerendered child component too gets rerendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) or [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to stop unnecessary re-rendering

in Item component like

```
class Item extends React.PureComponent {
 render(){
  return <div></div>
 }
}
```